# time compare in windows servuce

Tags: windows-services

I had written one windows service in C#.NET which fires on every miniutes... I want to execute certain code(some logic) on every month on say xyz date.... this task shld repeted on every month on same date... So can any one tell me how to do this..? I mean to say the block of code which i will write shld get executed on same date of every month...

Answer (score 1):

Deploy this as a scheduled task rather than a service.